# Homomorphism of the rings is zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Justify that each homomorphism ring $\mathbb{Z}_{43}$ in a ring $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$ is zero.

I know that homomomorphism in ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in a ring $\mathbb{Z}_1$ is zero, because they are cyclic and differ by one element.

How I can prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:\Bbb Z_{43}\to\Bbb Z_{42}$ is my homomorphism. Then $$f(x)=43f(x)=f(43x)=f(0)=0.$$

Comment: Can I use the theorem that "f:R->S, if R is body that f=0 or f-monomorphism"?

Comment: @KasiaPisaniak I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: I want use theorems: 
1) "f:R->S f- homomorphism, if R-body then f is zero or f - monomorphism"
2) "$Z_p$ - body <=> $p\in primes$

but I don't know how I can prove that R isn't monomorphism.

Comment: The term body is what some languages use to mean field. @Kasia: You could use that, but it would be missing the general point this exercise is trying to point out.

Comment: @KasiaPisaniak Isn't it obvious that $f$ is not a monomorphism? It it were you would have $|\Bbb Z_{43}|\le|\Bbb Z_{42}|$ which is false since $43>42$.

Comment: So.. If I take $\{42,0\}\in \mathbb{Z}_{43}$ and if I prove that injective isn't then I prove that isn't monomorphism! :D

Comment: @Kasia I'm not sure why you are going for such a complicated theorem when I just showed that there is a one-line direct proof. On the left you have $43=1$, on the right you have $43=0$ and thus $f(x)=0$ everywhere. No need for any advanced theorems here. Also, this shows that no ring structure is needed, this is true for any group homomorphism $\Bbb Z_{43}\to\Bbb Z_{42}$ (and I trust you can generalize this to $\Bbb Z_{n+1}\to\Bbb Z_n$ without trouble). At no point is $43\in\Bbb P$ needed.